# Auto-drive mapping for each user

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, group-policy, mappeddrive

I'm trying to auto map for each users in my AD a folder on the server/

So I'm trying to use the new feature in SBS/Server 08 :
User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Drive Maps

Action: Create

Location: \myServer\Personal Folders\%USERNAME%

Run in logged-on user's security context : Yes

So I was expecting that in the Shared "Personal Folders", a folder will be automatically create and will be displayed in the My Computer of each user, but no :(

I know that a KB is required for XP users, but for now I'm testing on my Windows 7.

- What kind of sharing permissions and security permissions do I have to configure on "Personal Folders" ?
- Create ? Update ?
- I want the user to be the only one that will have credentials.

My GPO is applied to the OU where my users are. I run a gpupdate /force and log off/on to check.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

For personal folders you're better off applying a [Folder Redirection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232692) policy to the users My Documents folders.  This will ensure that anything created in or copied to My Documents always goes to the server, and - as My Documents is the default save location for most apps - will cause you far less grief in the longer term.

It doesn't require a drive mapping, and you can configure this policy to move anything that may currently be in My Documents to the redirected server path.

Comment: I decided not to go for this solution because they can have big files in it and don't need to backup it and it would kill the bandwidth.

I really want to have folders for each of them, so they can backup the strict minimum and necessary files on the server which is raided.